# Convert QString to uint16*

Tags: c++, qt

Good day

I'm using a 3rd party library with functions have this sort of signature

```
int32 WebShot_Open(intptr WebShotHandle, uint16 *Url);
```

in Visual Studio, I can call this function using the following code

```
WebShot_Open(WebShotHandle, L"http://www.stackoverflow.com/")
```

I want to use this function from within Qt, and I want to pass `QString` to the 2nd parameter.

```
QString url = "www.stackoverflow.com";
WebShot_Open(WebShotHandle, url);
```

How to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use `utf16 ()` method - like `WebShot_Open (WebShotHandle, url.utf16 ())`